# jQuery - Apply style to center div in a three column row?

Tags: jquery, html, loops

I'm trying to add borders to the middle column in a three column row.  This:

```
var subcount = $j('#sub > div').size();
```

Gives me 6, and I'm trying to figure out how to apply a style to the divs in the middle? (in this case, div 2 and div 5)

```
<div id="sub">
<div>div 1</div> <div>div 2</div> <div>div3</div>
<div>div 4</div> <div>div 5</div> <div>div6</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to do that based on the div # and not the id?  Like, some sort of foreach loop or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this. It depends on how your data is structured. The brute force way if there are only 6 columns:

```
$("#sub > div:nth-child(2), #sub > div:nth-child(5)").css("border", "1px solid black");
```

You can also use an equation with `:nth-child`:

```
$("#sub > div:nth-child(3n+2)").css("border", "1px solid black");
```

Answer (score 0):

If those are indeed columns, you'd probably be better off using a real table as it's better suited for tabular data. You also haven't marked your rows, which makes selecting the columns difficult. One way to do it would be this:

```
var n = 1;
$('#sub > div').filter(function() { return n++ % 3 == 2 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you add some class in code behind, and then apply a clase selector. Or, better, a css style.

If you must use jQuery, cletus solution is just what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Array returned by JQuery is zero-indexed, just run something like this for "div" elements 2 and 5:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sub div").filter( function (i) {
        return i == 1 || i == 4;
    }).css("background", "#b4b0da");
});
```